# Async flow control without RxJS

Tags: javascript, promise, observable

I'm working on a mobile app and I want it to be offline-first.
Let's say I want to show the "Company" page so I request the company datas.

Here's what I do, I look for the company data in the local storage (indexedDB in my case) and at the same time I call the server for the same data (to get the potential updates). In each callback I update the view with the datas fetched. First updated from local datas then from remote datas.

To avoid a race condition I have a boolean called "remoteDataAlreadyFetched" that I check in my local storage callback (in case remote datas arrive before the storage response)

My question is: how should I handle this ? 2 separate promises in my view controller (one for local, one for remote) ? Should I use an observable ? This looks overkill since there won't be more than 2 responses (local and remote). Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot for your help

EDIT:

This is how I would do it with RxJS. Don't know if it's a bad practice to use Observables in this situation...

```
public static getOfflineFirstObservable(localCall, remoteCall): Observable<any> {
  const data$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  var hasFetchedRemoteData = false;

  localCall().then(localDatas => {
    if (!hasFetchedRemoteData) data$.next(localDatas);
  });

  remoteCall().then(remoteDatas => {
    data$.next(remoteDatas);
    hasFetchedRemoteData = true;
  });

  return data$.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're offline then trying to get remote data will result in rejected promises (with promise.race). If all you're trying to do is get item from cache first (if it's there) and if it's not try to get it remote you can do the following:

```
const cacheBuilder = promises => fetcher => setFn => getFn => url => {
  //using url as key but can be url+JSON.stringify(parameters)+method(GET/POST)
  const key = url;
  //get from cache first if exist
  return getFn(key).catch(()=>{
    if(promises[key]){
      return promises[key];//return active promise
    }
    promises[key]=fetcher(url);
    return promises[key];

  })
  .then(
    result=>{
      if(!promises[key]){//update cache, this will cause requests to server
        fetcher(url).then(result=>setFn(key,result)).catch(ignore=>ignore);
      }
      promises[key]=undefined;
      setFn(key,result);
      return result;
    }
  );
}

const cacheFirst = cacheBuilder(
  {}//store active promises here
)(
  //fetch function (can be $.get or something else)
  //  I am only using url here but you could use (url,params,method,headers) as well
  url=>
    //remove "console.log ||" it's to show that multiple active fetches share promises
    //  asking for fetch("/") multiple times while first time is not resolved
    //  will not cause multiple requests
    console.log("fetching:",url) ||
    fetch(url)
    .then(response=>response.text())
    .then(result=>result.substr(0,10))
)(
  //how to set an item in local storage
  (key,value)=>{
    newStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("netCache")||"{}");
    newStorage[key]=value;
    localStorage.setItem("netCache",JSON.stringify(newStorage));
  }
)(
  //how to get an item based on key (can be url or url + JSON.stringify(parameters) or url+params+method...)
  key=>
    Promise.resolve(
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("netCache")||"{}")[key] ||
      Promise.reject("Not in cache")
    )
);

Promise.all([//should not cause multiple requests, should have only one request made
  cacheFirst("/"),
  cacheFirst("/"),
  cacheFirst("/"),
  cacheFirst("/")
]).then(
  ()=>cacheFirst("/")//should come from cache as well, no request made
)
```

Here is an example where all implementation is in one function without passing fetch, getter and setter:

```
const cacheFirst = (promises => url => {
  //using url as key but can be url+JSON.stringify(parameters)+method(GET/POST)
  const key = url;
  const fetcher = url=>
    fetch(url)
    .then(response=>response.text())
    .then(result=>result.substr(0,10));
  const setFn = (key,value)=>{
    newStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("netCache")||"{}");
    newStorage[key]=value;
    localStorage.setItem("netCache",JSON.stringify(newStorage));
  }
  const getFn = key=>
    Promise.resolve(
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("netCache")||"{}")[key] ||
      Promise.reject("Not in cache")
    );
  //get from cache first if exist
  return getFn(key).catch(()=>{
    if(promises[key]){
      return promises[key];//return active promise
    }
    promises[key]=fetcher(url);
    return promises[key];
  })
  .then(
    result=>{
      //update cache if result didn't came from request, this will cause requests to server
      if(!promises[key]){
        fetcher(url)
        .then(result=>setFn(key,result))
        .catch(ignore=>ignore);
      }
      promises[key]=undefined;
      setFn(key,result);
      return result;
    }
  );
})({})//IIFE passing in the promises object to store active promises
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make my app appear as fast as possible. To do that, I want to immediately show the user the cached datas during the remote call. If he's offline then the remote call will just not return but it's ok. If the remote call returns then I want to update the cached and displayed datas. Thanks for your answer, I'm gonna take a deeper look into it

Comment: I'm reading over and over again your code and I have some difficulties understanding it, to be honest ^^" That's some next level sh*t. Is that functional programming ?

Comment: @Maslow updated the code to request the resource again when it came from cache and update the cache. If something goes wrong requesting the resource then the error is ignored and cache is not updated. Instead of passing in all the functions like fetcher, getter and setter you can code it into the function as well.

Comment: Ok that's far easier to read. So you store all the running promises to avoid making the same call several times... setFn just set a value in LS, ok... Didn't get the substr(0, 10) in fetcher function tho... Finally your promise only returns once, right ? I won't have my 2-steps display (cache data immediately... then fetched data when the query returns). This piece of code is a way to avoid identical calls to be made. It's cool, but does not resolve my issue, I think

Comment: @Maslow If data is not available in cache it'll try to get from network, if it was in cache then that is returned and cache is updated with network data (check the comment: `//update cache if result didn't came`). The subsr is just so you can run it in the console here and do not have very large strings, I'm using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) but as the comment indicates you can use jQuery or anything here, it's just a function that makes a network request and returns the result.

Comment: I see. So the user won't see the updated data right away, right ? It will show the cached data, then update the cache and only _the next time_ the user sees the screen he will see the updated data. That's it ? It could do the job in some case. Thanks

Comment: @Maslow Yes, cache first and refresh cache, on next request cache first (so the previously refreshed one) then refresh ... Since the user can be offline the refresh is optional and errors are ignored. If you want to fetch local and update when/if remote comes in you may have unexpected behavior like user is scrolling through info and remote data comes in so changes the page. However; if this is what you want then promise is probably not the right way to go but instead use callback, you can call a callback multiple times; once for local and once for remote.

Comment: Yes that's what I figured... Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting problem, so you are trying to make sure about the order of your two async operations.

I implement something that realize this, check my code below or just run them ;)

```
// two promise with no guaranteed order:
var localPromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 1000))
var remotePromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 1000))

// wrap them
var localFirst = Promise.resolve(localPromise)
    // can also add your handler for localdata
    .then(() => Promise.resolve(remotePromise))
var remoteFirst = Promise.resolve(remotePromise)

// viola
Promise.race([localFirst, remoteFirst]).then(console.log)
```

Comment: Interesting. The thing is there's no way localFirst wins the race right ? So why use the Promise.race() ? Also the idea was to write this logic in my provider so I can have a clean call in my view controller. In this case it looks like I would have to pass a callback function AND use the returned Promise to handle the "offline first" behavior, right ?

Comment: I'm wrong somehow, regardless of my answer, I think that you DO have to use two handlers when local  comes first then remote come back, which reminds me of Rxjs as well :) tho I'm not that into Rxjs. If you can accept that there should be two handlers then I think we can fix this without using Rxjs

Comment: I might not be helping here :(, but I think this problem should be generalized into some question like 'async flow control without rxjs' which might have a better clearance from a more constructive perspective.

Comment: Arf, ok. A friend of mine told me I could use Service workers but iOS support is not there yet. Ok I'll rename the issue then, thx Octave :)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally decided to create 2 separate promises. I get the local data (if exists) on page load and immediately try to fetch the remote data. So the user can see a content right away but still see a spinner on the top right indicating that's remote data have been requested. When the request comes back the view is updated.

I've decided to do that because the page also has a pull to refresh so it seemed smarter to separate the 2 calls (local and remote) to be able to call the server as many time as I wanted.

Thanks for your answers.
@HMR Your solution is really interesting but didn't really fit my needs. Thanks a lot